# How to get value of id and fill in a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a variable
`let a`
I want to fill an a variable with a id of tag div

ex:

```
<div id='1' className='card'>
  <button oneClick={() => toDo}>Click
  </button>
  <div className='card-body'>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='2' className='card'>
  <button oneClick={() => toDo}>Click
  </button>
  <div className='card-body'>
  </div>
</div> 
more...
```

When I click the button of card, do add value of id div in an a variable in React jd

Answer (score 1):

As the `id`s are unique, you can pass id to `toDo` function and assigned it to `let a`.

```
let a;

const toDo = (int id) => {
   a = id;
}
```

```
<div id='1' className='card'>
  <button oneClick={() => toDo(1)}>Click</button>
  <div className='card-body'></div>
</div>

<div id='2' className='card'>
  <button oneClick={() => toDo(2)}>Click</button>
  <div className='card-body'></div>
</div>
```